# Android:Load Custom URL on Notification Click

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-notifications

How do we create a notification that lands on a different page `internal asset`.

**Code**

```
Intent launchActivity = new Intent(ctx, CordovaApp.class);
launchActivity.putExtra("heading",newsHeader);
launchActivity.putExtra("content",newsText);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx,0, launchActivity,0);
//Create notification from the Pending Intent
```

By default this loads `file:///android_asset/www/index.html` on click of notification.

But I want to load another HTML of path

`file:///android_asset/www/templates/notification.html`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are u showing that in web view?

Comment: yes. its a Cordova based project

Comment: Then changing the path is not working? try putting index.html in templates.

Comment: that's the problem I don't specify the path. intent is created from the  context. I need to create intent from the URL.